# How to change Electron processes' names in development?

Tags: electron

I'm using VSCode's debugger to run the app. I want to change the names of the Electron processes to be the same as the packaged app (packaged with electron-builder). Is this possible?

This is what mine look like now:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: packaged with electron-builder, or electron-packager?

Comment: Hi @pushkin, I'm using electron-builder but I don't see how that is significant. The packaged app is working fine, the process names are ${APP_NAME} which is what I want. However, I want to change the the process names during development too.

I mean when I start the app like this: "node_modules/.bin/electron main.js"

Comment: @aabuhijleh did you found solution?

Comment: @aabuhijleh have u found a solution? when running with `electron .`?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, the `'FileDescription'` version string is used. Also see [electron/rcedit](https://github.com/electron/rcedit).

```sh
$ rcedit path-to.exe --set-version-string "FileDescription" "Your name"
```

Comment: how to set process name when running with `electron .`?